# Llamar método privado de una clase privada a la clase principal

Tags: java, poo

Hola quiero saber como llamar a un método privado (metodo_3) de una clase publica (Metodos) a la clase principal (MetodosMain), lo he realizado usando un método público intermediario (metodo_4), porque no recordaba como llamar al método privado en la clase principal .

Clase Publica Metodos

```
package paquete_1;

public class Metodos {

        public void numeros() {
            int i=1;
            while (i<=100) {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
            }
        }
        public static void num() {
            int par=2;
            while(par<=100) {
                System.out.println(par);
                par=par+2;
            }
        }
        private void metodo_3() {
            int impar=1;
            while(impar<=100) {
                System.out.println(impar);
                impar=impar+2;
            }
        }
        void metodo_4() {
            metodo_3();
        }
}
```

Clase Principal MetodosMain

```
package paquete_1;

public class MetodosMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Metodos nuevo=new Metodos();
        nuevo.numeros();
        System.out.println("Se uso el metodo numeros");
        Metodos.num();
        System.out.println("Se uso el metodo num");
        nuevo.metodo_4();
        System.out.println("Se uso el metodo_4 que a la vez hace uso del metodo_3");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

No puedes llamar un método `private` desde la clase `MetodosMain`, esto es lo que se conoce como encapsulamiento.

Por otro lado debes tener claro que `metodo_4()` solo visible dentro de las clases del paquete `paquete_1` porque no le especificas modificador de acceso. Si mueves cualquiera de las dos clases a otro paquete tampoco podrás llamarlo.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Metodos nuevo=new Metodos();


    //obtienes los metodos de la clase
    Method metodo = nuevo.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("metodo_3", new Class[0]);

    //poner accesible el metodo
    metodo.setAccessible(true);

    //invocar el metodo
    metodo.invoke(nuevo, new Object[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos privados solo funcionan dentro de la clase que se crearon por eso no puedes llamarlo desde la clase MetodosMain. Si necesitas usar el método 'private void metodo_3()' tienes que ponerlo como publico.